# Incomplete implementation of class method - what is missing?

Tags: objective-c, implementation, class-method

I have changed one of my instance methods to a class method so that it can be accessed from another class. The method is successfully called, but I have one warning on my code:

- Incomplete implementation (on the line '@implementation myViewController')

My class code looks like this:

```
//...

@implementation myViewController

#pragma mark - myMethod
+ (void)myMethod:(CustomUIView *)customView didSelectText:(NSString *)text
{
    //...
}

//...
```

In my class header file, I have the following:

```
#import "CustomUIView.h"

//...

@interface myViewController : CustomUIViewController <CustomUIViewDelegate>
{
    //...
}

//...

@end
```

I imagine I must be declaring the method in the wrong part of the header file, possibly due to the  clause? Or I'm missing something else altogether. I've had a good look around the net and [as far as I can tell I'm following protocol](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Writing_Objective-C_Class_Methods); perhaps there's something peculiar to my setup?

**Edit**: This is my protocol from my CustomUIView header file:

```
@class CustomUIView;

@protocol CustomUIViewDelegate <NSObject>

+ (void)myMethod:(CustomUIView *)customView didSelectText:(NSString *)text;
//...
@end
```

Comment: Where's your implementation of TSAlertView?

Comment: @HotLicks Had meant to change that to the generic 'myMethod'; hopefully the question makes more sense now.

Comment: If `CustomUIViewDelegate` says that `myMethod:` is an instance method, then a class method won't be seen as a match.  (Perhaps add the protocol definition to your question.)

Comment: @PhillipMills my code directs to the right place - the method is found. The only problem is that I have these warnings in my code...

Comment: @CaptainProg  ...which is why I said "won't be **seen** as a match".  If the compiler sees what it thinks is a required method in a protocol, it complains when it's not implemented.  If you don't actually call that method then nothing will trigger a run-time error.

Comment: I've updated my question to include the protocol definition, hopefully this will make things a little clearer?

Comment: The message is "myMethod in protocol not implemented"???  If so, where is the protocol that's declaring myMethod?

Comment: I have simplified the question and corrected all syntax issues suggested thus far. However, the problem remains the same. The question has been updated to reflect the current state of play.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake is in the name of the method. Implementation is `didSelectText` and interface is `didSelectTerm`. (Text vs Term -> obviously should be the same) Also, you call `[[self class] otherMethod:text];` as a class method, which, if you look closely, is not.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the text/term thing. However, I still receive the error...

Answer (score 0):

Your changes don't make sense.

You can access instance methods from other classes - they don't have to be class methods. Class methods means they are methods that are implemented by the class - not an instance of the class.

Secondly, within your new class method, you are calling a method (otherMethod:) which as an instance method, i.e. one that is called by an object of the class. Since you are calling it at `[[self Class] otherMethod:text]` this is wrong as [self Class] is used to call class methods, not instance methods. You don't have a valid reference to an object of your class to send the message to.

To add:

You've implemented a method:

```
+ (void)myMethod:(CustomUIView *)customView didSelectTerm:(NSString *)text;
```

but your protocol expects:

```
+ (void)termTextClickedOn:(TSAlertView *)customView didSelectTerm:(NSString *)term;
```

The names you give your actual parameters don't matter so the difference in text and term don't count, but the method names, as written in Objective-C boil down to:

```
+ myMethod:didSelectTerm:
```

and

```
+ termTextClickedOn:didSelectTerm:
```

Not only are the two names different, but the types of the first parameters are different as well, one takes a `CustomUIView *`, the other takes a `TSAlertView *`, which might work if one is a subclass of the other, but in any case, your method names are wrong.

Comment: now that you edit the answer, you got it right, wanted to edit my comment, but I was not able so I added another one to emphasise that

Comment: My apologies, I have been changing my method names to make my question a little more readable. In the first edit, I forgot to adjust my method names accordingly. The updated code reflects what I *should* have put initially.

Comment: Ah....it was *edit the answer*, not *the question*....and I was talking with Abizem....sorry for the confusion :)

Comment: @CaptainProg I think you're barking up the wrong tree. Fix the obvious problem - your delegate method is wrong. Within your delegate you are trying to do something to an object, but you are sending the message to a class.

Comment: @Abizern Could you elaborate on this please? Is the problem in my '@protocol CustomUIViewDelegate <NSObject>'? I understand that a class method acts on a class (as opposed to an instance method), so do I need to use an instance method instead?